# Java dealing with two custom deserializers

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility

so this is a very weird situation that I came across and have no idea how to handle.

I have a service that contains logic to deserialize an object from a request sent to it. Now the object in question is being changed and a new deserialization method is implemented to deal with that (don't ask why, all I know is we just need to change the method of deserialization).

The problem is that this change needs to be backwards compatible so we should be able to deal with both types of objects. In order to do this, we need to be able to determine the correct deserializer to use depending on the type of object but how do we do that if the object is serialized into a byte buffer? Im out of ideas... Is there a different/better way of going about this change?

The service is in Java.

**Edit 1: Clearing up my intentions** .
The old object used a custom serializer and the new one uses an ObjectMapper JSON serializer. So my goal is to be able to detect if I am dealing with the old or new object so I can deserialize accordingly.
I can try to use the new deserializer and catch the JsonParseException it throws and in the catch block, use the old serializer but this is not the way I want to handle a JsonParseException.

Comment: Are you talking about de-serialization from a byte array generated by the JVM, or from a string (such as with HTTP requests' body)?

Comment: The two objects are serialized in different ways. One of them uses a simple ObjectMapper with custom serializer and the other uses a custom serializer with an internal MediaType. Im not really sure on the inner workings of those serializers.

Comment: I go to have dinner, than I'll write the answer. I was expecting it to be related to JSON serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Do those two classes have a common base interface? Do the new one extend the old one?

Comment: No, the old object is a serializable object whereas the new one is just a Java object that is mapped to JSON serializer for serialization.

Comment: Could you post the "service" method signature? Which class does it return? In this case I suspect it returns Object

Comment: They deserialize into different objects so yes it returns Object. I ultimately want to change service logic so it handles differently based off the deserialized object. This is to make it backwards compatible.

Comment: See if the answer is acceptable for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to identify a *difference* between the new and the old object. You'll use that to switch to the old de-serializer.
You'll also need a specific `ObjectMapper` for these two classes, old and new.

Create a `Module`, and register it

```
final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Object.class, new NewDeserializer(new OldDeserializer()));

final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Prepare the new `StdDeserializer`, which will accept as constructor argument the old one.

```
public class NewDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Object> {
    private final StdDeserializer<Object> oldDeserializer;

    NewDeserializer(final StdDeserializer<Object> oldDeserializer) {
        super(NewObject.class);
        this.oldDeserializer = oldDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(
            final JsonParser parser,
            final DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
       final ObjectCodec codec = parser.getCodec();

       // Read the JSON document to a tree
       final TreeNode treeNode = codec.readTree(parser);

       // Identify if it is the new format, or the old one
       final TreeNode newField = treeNode.get("newField");

       if (newField == null) {
          // Delegate to the old de-serializer
          final JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory(parser.getCodec());
          final JsonParser oldParser = factory.createParser(treeNode.toString());
          return oldDeserializer.deserialize(oldParser, context);
       }

       return codec.readValue(treeNode.traverse(), NewObject.class);
    }
}
```

The old `StdDeserializer`

```
public class OldDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Object> {
    OldDeserializer() {
        super(OldObject.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(
            final JsonParser parser,
            final DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return parser.getCodec().readValue(parser, OldObject.class);
    }
}
```

Now, simply call

```
objectMapper.readValue(v, Object.class);
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't really know the internal workings of the ObjectMapper deserializer so the examples are very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Serializable classes should have a serialVersionUID that is static, final, and of type long.
This is to ensure that the class of the object that was serialized is same as the class of the object being deserialized.

In order to achieve backward compatibility follow these steps:

1. Ensure that whenever class structure is changed, you change the value of this field.
2. Use your new custom serializer to deserialize the object.
3. If the object is of the previous class you will get an **InvalidClassException**. Catch this exception and try to deserialize that object with the legacy deserializer inside catch block.

This ensures that your custom deserializer has backward compatability.

Comment: Very interesting. The new serialization is being done via ObjectMapper. Is there a way to set something similar to a serialVersionUID using that class? If so then a check for that will solve my problems as you mentioned.